# How to do Hidden Quest: Got the Basics?

Tags: hearthstone

How do you complete [Got the Basics](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Quest) hidden quest in Hearthstone? Would leveling all heroes to level 10 do?

> **Got the Basics!** : Collect every card in the Basic Set.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're exactly right.

There are two distinct groups of basic cards -- the neutral basic cards (of which you start play with all of them unlocked), and the class-specific basic crads (of which half start locked, and the other half is XP-locked).

The last basic cards for each class unlock at level 10, so if you level all 9 classes up to *at least* level 10, you will have acquired all of the basic cards, and trigger the hidden quest.